# Sum unique values with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Hello,
I need an equivalent formula to sum unique values based on some criteria.
The results I want is in column `E`. There are 2 criteria(first one on column D and the second one, column `B` must be `">10"`.

Now I use this formula:
`{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$10=D2,IF($B$2:$B$10>10,MATCH($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10,0))),ROW($B$2:$B$10)-ROW($B$2)+1),$B$2:$B$10))}`

The problem with this formula, is that it can't be set with `FormulaArray` in`VBA`.I understand that I can use `evaluate` to extract the result but all I want is to have a formula on every cell from column `E`, that can calculate correct.

Thank you !

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: Instead of using a formula, make use of a loop with nested IF criteria.

Comment: Maybe `Remove Duplicates` first then using a `SUMIFS` could do it.

Comment: @Luuklag In my personal case, this formula have 5 criteria and the result is the `denominator` of a fraction. And the `numerator` it's a `Sumifs` formula with also 5 criteria. Overall it's a little bit difficult to be implement.

Comment: @newacc2240 It's a good idea, I will check if that can work in others exemples.

Comment: "The problem with this formula, is that it can't be set with FormulaArray inVBA.": Why not? Just:  `Range("E2").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$10=D2,IF($B$2:$B$10>10,MATCH($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10,0))),ROW($B$2:$B$10)-ROW($B$2)+1),$B$2:$B$10))" : Range("E2:E4").FillDown`

Comment: @AxelRichter I do not know why it didn't work. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to try a couple methods before I found one that works, but I got 'er figured out.

Paste these functions into a module:

```
Public Function SumIfIf(rgeData As Range, matchCriteria As String, numCompCriteria As String) As Double

    Dim c As Range, arr_Distinct() As String, x As Long, totalOut As Double, str_ConcatRgeRow As String
    ReDim arr_Distinct(0)
    
    totalOut = 0
    If InStr("<>=", Left(numCompCriteria, 1)) = 0 Then numCompCriteria = "=" & numCompCriteria

    For Each c In rgeData.Columns(1).Cells
        str_ConcatRgeRow = c.Value & c.Offset(0, rgeData.Columns.Count - 1).Value
        If Not IsInArray(arr_Distinct, str_ConcatRgeRow) Then
            ReDim Preserve arr_Distinct(UBound(arr_Distinct) + 1)
            arr_Distinct(UBound(arr_Distinct)) = str_ConcatRgeRow
            If Evaluate(c.Value = matchCriteria) And Evaluate("=(" & c.Offset(0, rgeData.Columns.Count - 1).Value & numCompCriteria & ")") Then
                totalOut = totalOut + c.Offset(0, rgeData.Columns.Count - 1).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    
    SumIfIf = totalOut

End Function

Function IsInArray(arrToCheck As Variant, valToFind As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim x As Long
    IsInArray = False
    For x = 1 To UBound(arrToCheck)
        If arrToCheck(x) = valToFind Then IsInArray = True
    Next x
End Function
```

In the case of your example, you'd use it like this:

[image: SumIfIf Screenshot]

> **Usage**:
>
> SumIfIf(rgeData As Range, matchCriteria As String, numCompCriteria As String)
>
> `rgeData`  =  a range of any number of rows and at least 2 columns
>
> The function matches:
>
> - the left-most column for exact matches to 'matchCriteria', and
> - the right-most column for matches to 'numCompCriteria'
>
> ...and then:
>
> - returns the sum of `numCompCriteria` matches
> - where `[matchCriteria] + [numCompCriteria]` is unique.
>
> `matchCriteria` = a text or numeric identifier, to be matched exactly
>
> `numCompCriteria` = a numeric identifier specific as a string starting with **>** or **<** or **=** like you would specify simple criteria for the `SumIf` worksheet function.
>
> - Examples of `numCompCriteria`: `"=10"`, `"<=10"`, `"10"`

I'm at my screen-time limit for the day; Let me know if you want further explanation. In the meantime hopefully this solves your issue.  :)

+1 to the Question for the challenge, which had the bonus of being *just* what I needed for something I'm working on too!

---

Update, further to @BOB's question:

The line of code that does the comparison is this one:

```
If Evaluate(c.Value = matchCriteria) And Evaluate("=(" & c.Offset(0, rgeData.Columns.Count - 1).Value & numCompCriteria & ")") Then
```

so depending on your needs there are a few ways you could change it.

Quick and dirty, if your new criteria is permanent, replace the above line with:

```
If Evaluate(c.Value = matchCriteria) _
    And Evaluate("=(" & c.Offset(0, rgeData.Columns.Count - 1).Value & ">10" & ")") _
    And Evaluate("=(" & c.Offset(0, rgeData.Columns.Count - 1).Value & "<=35" & ")") _
    Then
```

Note that this won't be using the value of `numCompCriteria` anymore but you'd still have to specify something, or else remove the argument from the function declaration. Or, adjust it add more parameters for your new criteria.

Following that pattern you can add all the criteria you like. The way it's used here, "`Evaluate`" is returning True or False.  You can demonstrate with:

```
debug.print Evaluate ("=(10>35)")
```

and in the code above

```
c.Offset(0, rgeData.Columns.Count - 1).Value
```

returns the value of the right-most column.

Comment: Congratulation for your work you've done a great job ! I have one question, if I want to add another criteria, how can I write the formula? for example (column `B` <=35). `=SumIfIf($A$2:$B$10,D2,">10"&"<=35")`  the result with this formula is 0 . Another specification for your solution is to be careful on the formula because is Case Sensitive.

Comment: will the criteria always be `">10"&"<=35"` or will it vary?  Will you need additional criteria on top of those?

Comment: You're welcome.  Hopefully you can make sense of how the code works, and then adjust it to your exact needs.